# Trouble inserting an Item at the End of a Linked list Java not Working

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to add an item at the end of my Linked List, but I get the following Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at List.insertAtEnd(List.java:105)
    at MainProgram.stringOperation(MainProgram.java:178)
    at MainProgram.main(MainProgram.java:97)



 class Link
    {
       public Object data;
       public Link next;
    }  


// List Class Method:insertAtEnd: insert a given item at the end of the list - 
       public void insertAtEnd(Object item)
       {
             //Create a New Link    
             Link newLink = new Link();
             newLink.data = item;
             newLink.next = null;
          
             //Set _tail to point to null
             _tail.next = newLink;
             _tail = newLink;
             
          
             //Add to  the Counter - For the Number of Elements in the Linked List
             _numOfElements++;
       }
```

Main Program - One of the Methods

```
//StringOperations
   public static void stringOperation(int option)
   {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      //Variables needed from User
      int index, startPosition, endPosition;
      String data;
      
      //Instances needed to Perform Operations (1-9)
      Link link;
      List listOfIndexes;
      
      
      //Switch Statement to Perform Operations
      switch(option)
      {
        
         
         //Operation 3: insertAtEnd
         case 3:
            System.out.print("Please enter a String: ");
            data = keyboard.nextLine();
            
            stringList.insertAtEnd(data);
            
            System.out.println("Completed Operation 3 for the String List." + "\n");
            break;
         
         
      }
   }
```

I wanted to add more code, but I keep getting an error on StackOverflow in order for you all to better understand. I need to make sure my tail is updating whenever I add an item to the Linked List in order to have a more efficient program.

Updated Version:

```
 private Link _head;
   private Link _tail;
   private int _numOfElements = 0;
   
   /*Public Methods */
   
   //(1) initialize: create an empty list (no items) - DONE!
   public List()
   {
      _head = null;
      _tail = null;
   }
```

Comment: Which line is 105 and what is _tail?

Comment: I think _tail is null. please show the code where you have defined it and used it.

Comment: private Link _head;
   private Link _tail;
   private int _numOfElements = 0;
   
   /*Public Methods */
   
   //(1) initialize: create an empty list (no items) - DONE!
   public List()
   {
      _head = null;
      _tail = null;
   }

Comment: Yup _tail is null. you cant use _tail.next before assigning _tail with a value.

Comment: Would it be the following:

  //Create a New Link    
         Link newLink = new Link();
         newLink.data = item;
         newLink.next = null;
      
         //Set _tail to point to null
         _tail = newLink;
         _tail.next = newLink;

Answer (score 0):

A list is by default sorted the way you inserted the items:

```
java.util.List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add("First item");
list.add("Second item");
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant reference tail.next before assigning _tail a value.

just use this in insertAtEnd function:

```
if(_tail != null){
           _tail.next = newLink;
    }
            _tail = newLink;
```

Comment: Faizan, thank you for your help! I did what you suggested; however, my toString method does not print out the string I enter

Comment: I think it works now. I add an item at the first index and then I use the insertEnd method and it work. Whenever I use the insertEnd method first without adding any items - I don't get any errors; however, my toString doesn't display my item. Thank you, Fazian!